# Canvas context.measureText is not giving accurate results

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am testing the `context.measureText` in `Chrome v106.0.5249.91` and am getting some inconsistent results.

The following are character strings tested and the resulting widths:

```js
"888" = 50.0537109375
"881" = 50.0537109375
"811" = 48.3984375
"111" = 46.7431640625
```

There is a clear difference as I substitute `8`'s for `1`'s in the string, but why is `888` reporting *the same* width as `881`?

```js
function getTextWidth(text, font) {
  // if given, use cached canvas for better performance
  // else, create new canvas
  var canvas = getTextWidth.canvas || (getTextWidth.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"));
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.font = font;
  var metrics = context.measureText(text);
  return metrics.width;
};

console.log(getTextWidth("888", "bold 30px helvetica")); // = 50.0537109375

console.log(getTextWidth("881", "bold 30px helvetica")); // = 50.0537109375

console.log(getTextWidth("811", "bold 30px helvetica")); // = 48.3984375

console.log(getTextWidth("111", "bold 30px helvetica")); // = 46.7431640625
```

EDIT: Now tested with several browsers. All can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have 4 times the same measure running the snippet (mobile android firefox)....

Comment: I think this might be related to the pixel density of the device, interpolation can be different from one to another. More density = more accuracy.

Comment: The weird thing is that  the difference between example 1 and 2 is 0 but the difference between the others is 1.6552734375. This means it is calculating the difference between a ```1``` and an ```8``` consistently/correctly two out of three times?!?

Comment: When you tried mobile browsers, did they have access to the Helvetica font? Without a valid font there is no guarantee that any calculation will be accurate.
Is there a different (android default) variable-width font to test with on your mobile browser?

Comment: Same result using arial. I can't be sure but I'm pretty much convinced that this is  related to the OpenGL (or what is in place of it) interpolation between the device physical pixel density and  the virtual pixel density of the browser canvas API. It has to be device dependent and platform dependent and it can't be perfectly linear. This is my guess but  I haven't check the low level implementation of the canvas api...

Comment: Thanks for the input. It just does seem a little odd that it 'sort of works'.